# Error In IDE Android Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio

What is this error?

> Error:Failed to open zip file.
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after
>   a network connection timeout.) Re-download
>   dependencies and sync project (requires network) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
>   network)

Answer (score 0):

When setting up one of the new boxes in the office recently, I ended up running across this.

At some point in the upgrade process I believe that it gets confused and finds itself in potentially bad states.  In order to resolve the problem, I deleted the .gradle folder at the user level above my project folder.

../AndroidStudioProjects

Once this was deleted, the application should then go out and try to re-download the components that it needs for the current environment. You may additionally need to install and update features in the console at the bottom of the screen as you go.  These will be suggestions from Android Studio after it is done downloading the updated files.  Once everything is updated, you should be good to go.